# How can I get the bullet elements to stay aligned with the image as the window shrinks?

Tags: html, css

Using relative positioning, when the window is full screen on my laptop it works perfectly, however, once I make it slighly smaller, by like 20px, the bullets become unaligned. Is there anyway to make these bullets stay aligned?

HTML.

```
<div id="mapdiv">
    <img id="map" src="images/map117.jpg">
    <a class="battlebullets" id="b1" href="RomanBattles117.html#battlerow1">⬤</a>
</div>
```

CSS.

```
#map { 
position: relative;
width: 100%; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

}

```
.battlebullets {
font-size: 7px;
color: #F0BC42;
position: absolute;
```

}

```
#b1 {
top: 80%;
right: 45%;
```

}

https://codepen.io/epzo/pen/aaKVGx

Answer (score 0):

Your map wrapper should have the relative positioning on it, not the image itself. Because of this, the percentages on your bullets for positioning are relative to the viewport instead of the map wrapper.

When you set a relative position on the map wrapper and also use a viewport relative font size, your bullet will now stay in place, and also get smaller as needed on smaller viewport sizes.

I updated your codepen with these changes. Note the relative position on the wrapper (I removed it from the image) and the `1vmax` font size.

https://codepen.io/brianespinosa/pen/BOVYab